Why does type inference fail for nested object arrays in this generic function?
I'm trying to create a strongly-typed function in TypeScript that ensures consistency between two properties, attrA and attrB, in both individual objects and arrays of objects. Here's my setup:
type PARAM = { [k: string]: string }

type TYPE<T extends PARAM> = {
  attrA: T,
  attrB: { [k in keyof T]: null },
}

// This works as expected
function fn1<T extends PARAM>(a: TYPE<T>) { }

fn1({
  attrA: { a: 'a' },
  attrB: { a: null } // OK because 'a' is in attrA
})

fn1({
  attrA: { b: 'b' },
  attrB: { z: null } // Error: Property 'z' does not exist on type '{ b: null; }'.
})

However, when I try to extend this behavior to arrays, the type check fails:
function fn2<T extends PARAM>(a: TYPE<T>[]) { }

fn2([
  {
    attrA: { a: 'a' },
    attrB: { a: null } 
  }, {
    attrA: { b: 'b' },
    attrB: { z: null } // should be an error but it's not
  },
])

In the second example, I expect the attrB key to always match the keys of attrA for each element of the array. However, TypeScript does not throw an error for the mismatched keys (z not in attrA).
Why does TypeScript fail to enforce this type constraint for arrays, and how can I fix it so that fn2 properly validates the relationship between attrA and attrB for each object in the array?

UPDATE:
It would work if I define several generic Tⁿ, but this is unfeasible, this needs to be done dynamically
function fn2<T1 extends PARAM, T2 extends PARAM>(...a: [TYPE<T1>, TYPE<T2>]) { }

fn2(
  {
    attrA: { a: 'a' },
    attrB: { a: null }
  },
  {
    attrA: { b: 'b' },
    attrB: { z: null } // Error: Property 'z' does not exist on type '{ a: null; }'.
  },
)


• PARAM<any> isn't a thing; please [edit] to make sure this is a [mre] where the only problems are the ones you're asking about. • I don't see you trying to constrain an array, just a single type argument for one TYPE. If you want to talk about an array of these, then you need to use something like a mapped array/tuple type as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

Did you look at the playground link I showed above?  It's a link to a TypeScript IDE showing a working version of your code. That's how you should approach this, where you have an array of constraints. I understand the problem (or at least, I believe I do). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, please [edit] to show what doesn't work about it.

here is an exemple: Playground Link

No, it's not appropriate to expand the scope to a followup question after your question is addressed. If you solve one problem and run into another, then you should ask that as a separate question post. Is that acceptable to you? Let me know how to proceed.

You are right, it is a new issue. so I created a new post for it.
How to Type Multiple Parameterized Generics in TypeScript with Interdependent Types?
I believe these two issues are closely related, so I’ll link them here for better context.
can you help me with this new issue too?

I will take a look at that new issue when I get a chance, but I don't know if I can solve it yet.

You really want each argument to have its own type argument to put in TYPE<?>. If you use just one, then at best you'll get the union of all the intended type arguments together, and then it will start accepting things you don't want.
The way to represent this constraint is by making fn2 generic in the tuple type of all the intended type arguments, and then map it to the tuple of function parameters:
function fn2<T extends PARAM[]>(a: { [I in keyof T]: TYPE<T[I]> }) { }

Here a is of the mapped type {[I in keyof T]: TYPE<T[I]>}, so if T is [X, Y, Z], then a is of the type [TYPE<X>, TYPE<Y>, TYPE<Z>]. Let's test it out:
fn2([
  {
    attrA: { a: 'a' },
    attrB: { a: null } // okay
  }, {
    attrA: { b: 'b' },
    attrB: { z: null } // error!
  },
])
// <[{ a: string; }, { b: string; }]>

Looks good. The type argument T is inferred as [{a: string}, {b: string}] and so the first argument is checked against TYPE<{a: string}> (which succeeds) and the second is checked against TYPE<{b: string}> (which fails), as desired.
Playground link to code
